Sci-fi book I read in 1989 where most people live in arcologies, but some people live outside clinging to the tower grapples and harnesses
I read this book in 8th grade, it may have been an young-adult novel.
I think the main character makes their living by recording 'news' on the outside, and by maybe being a courier.
The key features were that the main character drove a motorcycle where the wheels automatically produced grapples as the wheels turned so they could ride up and down the sides of the tower of the arcology. When they slept they had a harness and boots that held them to the side of the tower.
The only thing I really remember about the plot was that the main character finds what they call a cherub I think.  It is a human that lives in the clouds and flies by being supported by bags of gas on their bodies instead of wings.  I believe they find an injured one of these cherubs and helps them.  At the same time they are trying to like sell the footage of these cherubs but are being chased.
I think the main character may have been a young woman but I am not sure.

This is Farewell Horizontal by K.W. Jeter.
The story is set in a single gigantic structure. The main character is a freelance journalist/artist.

You're either on the inside or the outside -- and either way, you're in trouble. A hustling young artist finds himself on the run from warring tribes, mysterious conspirators, body-swapping hackers and more, as he tries to both survive and strike it rich on the vertical surface of a skyscraper big enough to be its own world.

There are "angels" that use organic gas bags to stay afloat.

Anyone watching the tape might have thought the female angel was sleeping, until the reverse zoom from her tranquil face revealed the torn and deflated membrane, no longer a sphere behind her shoulders. She had lain swathed in the billowing folds, which when taut with blood-rendered gases would have borne her aloft.


Yes it is the link to the cover confirmed it thanks!
